# Extending a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, x-editable

I'm working on a page that use the X-editable library with Bootstrap 3; I have multiples instances of plugins. But, for some cases, I need a custom button template, then I change that with global option:

```
$.fn.editableform.buttons
```

But this change all X-editable instances. Is there a way that I can customize only one instance? How can I write a jQuery plugin that extends the same as the original, but with my own default settings?

I tried this so far:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.customEditable = function(settings) {

        this.editable = $.fn.editable(settings);
        this.editable.editableform.buttons = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm editable-trigger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button>';

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You can create a new Element dinamically...